# Crawling By Next Page Link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm writing a crawler to extract recipe href links on wikipedia. Based on my implementation, how can I continue to append links until I've reached the last page? Note: the next page link is titled "next 200".

The links are listed here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Recipes

```
def fetch_links(self, proxy):
    """Extracts filtered recipe href links

    Args:
      proxy: The configured proxy address.

    Raises:
      ValueError: If proxy is not a valid address.

    """
    if not self._valid_proxy(proxy):
        raise ValueError('invalid proxy address: {}'.format(proxy))
    self.browser.set_proxies({'http': proxy})
    page = self.browser.open(self.wiki_recipes)
    html = page.read()

    link_tags = SoupStrainer('a', href=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=link_tags)
    recipe_hrefs = r'^\/wiki\/Cookbook:(?!recipes|table_of_contents).*$'
    return [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all(
        'a', href=re.compile(recipe_hrefs, re.IGNORECASE))]
```

Comment: can you not just check if (next 200) element exists and follow until exhaustion?

Comment: I suppose, but clicking the next 200 would ensure I'm only looking for recipe links. Unless you have another idea.

Comment: I think you want all the recipe links from that 2k + records don't you? then just crawl all recipe links on each page, and follow the (next 200) and repeat until exhausted... then you will have all recipes links at the end

Comment: Correct. How can I do this though? I understand the browser object has a follow_link method.

Comment: normally I use `scrapy` for this task. but the same concept applies. you create a function and take **url** as argument, pass the *start url* initially, and crawl all recipe links and append to a global list using *xpath* (faster than regex.regex also works). then return the (next 200) link as the argument and call the same function. `try/except` for exhaustion and export the list. job done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the method I suggested in your comment, here is a code example using `urllib` and `re`, which the techniques are reusable in your code.

you create a function and take url as argument, pass the start url initially, and crawl all recipe links and append to a global list using regex. then get the **(next 200)** link as the argument and call the same function. `try/except` for exhaustion and export the list.

Since you have a *class* which the code isn't shown, I'm going to skip all `class` and `proxy` parts, here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import re

base_url = 'http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Recipes'
next_base = 'http://en.wikibooks.org'
recipes = []

# this is just the sample function
# you should handle your proxy logic here too
def get_links(url):
    request = urllib.urlopen(url)
    content = request.read()
    # I just use one-off re expression
    links = re.findall(r'/wiki/Cookbook:(?!Recipes)(?!Table_of_Contents).*" ', content)

    global recipes
    recipes += links

    try:
        # again, one-off re expression
        next_url = re.findall(r'/w/index.*>next 200', content)[0].split('\" ')[0]
        print "fetching next url: " + str(next_base + next_url)
        return get_links(next_base + next_url)
    except IndexError:
        print "all recipes fetched."
        print recipes
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "start fetching..."
    get_links(base_url)
```

Hope you get the techniques required.

Comment: Very nice, I was actually going to solve this recursively after thinking about the problem more. It's always shorter that way and it's virtually what I would do if I solved this with a while loop and created a stack to reference the visited urls. Thanks for the help, I can definitely solve this for sure now.

Comment: @TheGrayFox, glad it helps. I do scraping for work a lot, and I found using either `scrapy` or `lxml`+`urllib` will be more productive. `BeautifulSoup` is good too, but performance wise I believe `scrapy` is faster. And using `xpath` will definitely help boost it